# invoke function which accept "chan interface{}"

Tags: go, casting, channel

To the people who down voted this question - it does have a legitimate answer, which is reflection (see below).

I want to create a generic function where I can pass any channel to it and it will tell me how much of its capacity is filled.  I'm finding it annoying that I have to cast the channel to "chan interface{}".

My question is, for the function `foo` below, I can pass a string to it and that's fine.  Go accepts that as an interface{}.  Why does it not behave the same for channels?  Can I create a function which accepts a generic `chan interface{}`?

```
func testFoo() {
    str := "anything"
    foo(str)  //This is fine.
    aChan := make(chan string, 10)

    //This line doesn't compile.  Can I avoid casting to chan interface{}?
    CheckChanLen(aChan) 
}

func foo(obj interface{}) {}

func CheckChanLen(aChan chan interface{}) {
    chanCap := cap(aChan)
    chanLen := len(aChan)
    fmt.Printf("len:%d cap:%d", chanLen, chanCap)
}
```

Comment: You cannot, composite types in Go are not covariant.

Comment: You can pass a `string` to a function taking an `interface{}` because `string` fulfills `interface{}`. The channel parameter's type is `chan interface{}`; that's a specific type, not an interface. No other type can "fulfill" `chan interface{}` because it isn't an interface, so you can *only* pass a `chan interface{}` to it, nothing else.

Comment: Go doesn't have casting at all, so no matter what you do, you will avoid "casting to chan interface{}".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

`chan interface{}` is a different type to `interface{}`.

`interface{}` is a catch-all for all types, but `chan interface{}` is *NOT* a catch-all for all `chan` types.

Generics will bring this capability, but they are not in the go language ([yet](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-generics-overview.md)).

---

If all you need to do is check for channel capacity/length you can use the `reflect` package like so:

```
import "reflect"

func CheckChanLen(aChan interface{}) {
        rv := reflect.ValueOf(aChan)
        if rk := rv.Kind(); rk != reflect.Chan {
                panic("expecting type: 'chan ...'  instead got: " + rk.String())
        }           

        chanCap := rv.Cap()
        chanLen := rv.Len()
        fmt.Printf("len:%d cap:%d\n", chanLen, chanCap)
}
```

Comment: This is probably the right answer and I'm looking forward to generics being introduced (thanks for the link).  I'm going to wait a few days before marking your answer accepted in the hopes that someone has a clever idea.

Comment: Understood. I ran into this exact issue a couple months ago writing a generic channel unmarshaler. Since I was already using reflection, it was not a big deal to ensure the user's `interface{}` input was of base-type chan - but this of course was a runtime check  - and not a compile-time check - like you are looking for.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the OP's specific question. However, the OP's question seems to be an XY problem (as are about 99.9% of questions answered by generics--thus my dread for the day Go supports generics). If the OP will elaborate on their actual _goal_, I'm sure someone can come up with a clever solution to _that_.